# Memory location of data table for Modbus TCP

Tags: memory, plc, modbus

I have a Modbus TCP connection between two units.

Let's say that

PLC_A (Client) <-> PLC_B (Server)

Since they are using a Modbus TCP connection one can write to a certain coil address and the other one can read that data.

For example, A can write on address 0 and B can read from this address.

Where is the complete data table stored, is it stored in the server or the client? More specifically who is the bottleneck in this connection, and limits the size of the memory map of the data table?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I am not sure what is not making sense?..

Comment: The datagram of the package sent to the slave contains a start address, of an data table.. but where is this data table stored?

Answer (score 1):

A Modbus coil address isn't in any way related to an actual memory address.  It's really an identifier of "some output thingy somewhere".  It's up to the slave to determine what to do when a specific coil address is specified -- it might store a value in RAM, flip an output bit directly, trigger some other action, or simply ignore it.